# DOMXPath/DOMDocument - How to fetch foreach of many elements with same attribute

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I am using DOMXPath and DOMDocument to fetch data from HTML output source.

Here is my code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$name = $xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Model"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

When i `echo $name` i receive only the first result which this code is finding.
There are much more elements with `<td class=" " data-column-name="Model">` but this code is giving me only the first result. Do i have to make any foreach or while loop and how to get all results ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop like:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//td[@data-column-name="Model"]')) as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: But what if i have to find other elements and include them also in this foreach. For example `td[@data-column-name="RAM"]` How can i combine them in this foreach loop ?

Comment: I believe that would require a separate xpath query and iteration over it's results

Comment: Use a loop like:

    foreach ($xpath->query('//td/@data-column-name')) as $item) {
        echo $item->nodeValue.'<br>';
    }